# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function with react-select-search (npm package)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

[image]

My npmDropdown Component:

```
import SelectSearch from 'react-select-search';
import React from 'react';
export const Search = (props) => {
    console.log(props.countries);
    return (
    <SelectSearch options={props.countries} value="sv" name="language" placeholder="Choose your language" />
    );
};
```

My App.js file which is rendered:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import {Search} from './components/npmDropdown';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const options = [
      {name: 'Swedish', value: 'sv'},
      {name: 'English', value: 'en'},
      {
          type: 'group',
          name: 'Group name',
          items: [
              {name: 'Spanish', value: 'es'},
          ]
      }
    ];
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Search countries={options} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I had followed instructions listed here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select-search

Also, if someone can suggest another npm package with similar dropdown with search functionality.

Comment: check this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-j2qpwr  It seems working fine.

Comment: That error makes me think it's a webpack issue. My guess is look at either import or export on that file that calls into that module.

Comment: @AmareshSM  please go through the package once to see its functionality.

Comment: @Dom I researched it and it is an import issue but do I need to worry about the internals of the package when the doc or the usual approach states that just installing and importing the specific component should do the job. The only approach I will have to take  if I absolutely want to use it would be forking and make my own local changes but that defeats the purpose of using an npm package.

Comment: If issue is with the npm package, you can raise an issue on the repo. The repo is active and the issue will be addressed in some time.

Comment: For anyone who is looking for such a functionality, use this : https://ghoshnirmalya.github.io/react-search-box/  .